# Facebook api only gives me message updates

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a need to get Facebook page feeds for my application.
I am using "facebook/php-sdk-v4": "~5.0",
And my api version is v2.4

I have the facebook page id and access token

I made GET request on url  /{$pageId}/feed

It gives me result like 
Page added a new photo. (but not the photo link)
I used previous api v2.3 with (old version facebook-php-sdk) which gives me whole feed information.

I tried with v2.3 but seems like this sdk is not working good with v2.3

is there any way to achieve this by v2.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/{$pageId}/feed?fields=message,link`.

As of Graph API 2.4, you must explicitly ask for fields you want with the `fields` parameter. See the [Graph API changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog).